# Android Studio Gradle build script not working

Tags: android, gradle, mifos

This is the build script used by an Android client built on top of the MifosX platform for the mifos user community.

```
/*
 * This project is licensed under the open source MPL V2.
 * See https://github.com/openMF/android-client/blob/master/LICENSE.md
 */

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
        classpath 'com.github.triplet.gradle:play-publisher:1.1.4'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    maven { url 'http://dl.bintray.com/amulyakhare/maven' }
}
....
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply from: '../config/quality/quality.gradle'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
apply plugin: 'com.github.triplet.play'

....
dependencies {
    // You must install or update the Support Repository through the SDK manager to use this dependency.
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'src/main/libs')
    //DBFlow dependencies
    apt "com.github.Raizlabs.DBFlow:dbflow-processor:$rootProject.raizLabsDBFlow" compile "com.github.Raizlabs.DBFlow:dbflow-core:$rootProject.raizLabsDBFlow" compile "com.github.Raizlabs.DBFlow:dbflow:$rootProject.raizLabsDBFlow"
    // App's Support dependencies, including test
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion" compile "com.android.support:support-v4:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion" compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion" compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion" compile "com.android.support:design:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion" compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:$rootProject.playServicesVersion" compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:$rootProject.playServicesVersion" compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:$rootProject.playServicesVersion" compile "com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:$rootProject.mapUtilsServices" compile "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-idling-resource:$rootProject.espressoVersion"
    //Dagger dependencies
    apt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$rootProject.daggerVersion" compile "com.google.dagger:dagger:$rootProject.daggerVersion" provided 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
    //Required by Dagger2
    //Butter Knife
    compile "com.jakewharton:butterknife:$rootProject.butterKnifeVersion" apt "com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:$rootProject.butterKnifeVersion"
    //Square dependencies
    compile("com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$rootProject.retrofitVersionLatest") {
        // exclude Retrofit’s OkHttp peer-dependency module and define your own module import
        exclude module: 'okhttp'
    }
    compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$rootProject.retrofitVersionLatest" compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:$rootProject.retrofitVersionLatest" compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:$rootProject.retrofitVersionLatest" compile "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:$rootProject.okHttp3Version" compile "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:$rootProject.okHttp3Version" compile "com.jakewharton.fliptables:fliptables:$rootProject.flipTableVersion" compile 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0@jar'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.1.0'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.4'
    compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.3.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho-okhttp3:1.3.1'
    compile 'com.joanzapata.iconify:android-iconify-material:2.1.1'
    // (v2.0.0)
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.6@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'com.amulyakhare:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    // Android Testing Support Library's runner and rules
    androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test:runner:$rootProject.runnerVersion" androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test:rules:$rootProject.rulesVersion"
    // Espresso UI Testing dependencies.
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
    androidTestCompile("com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:$rootProject.espressoVersion") {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'recyclerview-v7'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'design'
    }
    androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:$rootProject.espressoVersion" testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
}
```

However whenever I build this script I get this error:

```
Error:(135, 1) A problem occurred evaluating project ':mifosng-android'.
> Could not find method compile() for arguments [com.github.Raizlabs.DBFlow:dbflow-core:3.1.1] on DefaultExternalModuleDependency{group='com.github.Raizlabs.DBFlow', name='dbflow-processor', version='3.1.1', configuration='default'} of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dependencies.DefaultExternalModuleDependency.
```

I am using Android Studio 2.1.1.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line above dependancies

`def raizLabsDBFlow= "4.0.1"`

Comment: the version number is already defined in the project wide build script

Answer (score 0):

In new android project  build script and move into setting grdle.

**setting.gradle**

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

[image]

Have a good day!